# Calculating column rows from other column rows iteration

Tags: python, pandas, calculated-columns

I'm trying to do some calculations, and put them into new named columns, by taking a values from rows, calculated from a formula, and two different columns for the same rows. 
Here is an example of the data and the calculated columns:

```
X   Y   TEMP    Data_1  Data_2  Data_3  Data_4
0   0   30  519 521 521 521
0   0   45  568 569 570 570
0   0   60  617 618 619 619
0   0   85  701 701 703 703
0   1   30  532 533 533 532
0   1   45  580 581 580 580
0   1   60  628 629 629 629
0   1   85  711 710 711 712
0   2   30  512 513 514 512
0   2   45  560 561 562 560
0   2   60  609 610 611 609
0   2   85  692 691 694 691
0   3   60  617 617 619 618
0   3   85  700 699 702 701
0   4   30  520 521 522 521
0   4   45  568 569 570 570
0   4   60  617 617 619 618
0   4   85  700 699 702 701
```

Here is how I am trying to get the output to look like:

```
X   Y   TEMP    Data_1  Data_2  Data_3  Data_4  Calculated_1    Calculated_2    Calculated_3    Calculated_4
0   0   30  519 521 521 521 Col A, Rows (2:5) and Data 1 Rows (2:5) Col A, Rows (2:5) and Data 2 Rows (2:5) Col A, Rows (2:5) and Data 3 Rows (2:5) Col A, Rows (2:5) and Data 4 Rows (2:5)
0   0   45  568 569 570 570             
0   0   60  617 618 619 619             
0   0   85  701 701 703 703             
0   1   30  532 533 533 532 Col A, Rows (6:9) and Data 1 Rows (6:9) Col A, Rows (6:9) and Data 2 Rows (6:9) Col A, Rows (6:9) and Data 3 Rows (6:9) Col A, Rows (6:9) and Data 4 Rows (6:9)
0   1   45  580 581 580 580             
0   1   60  628 629 629 629             
0   1   85  711 710 711 712             
0   2   30  512 513 514 512 Col A, Rows (10:13) and Data 1 Rows (10:13) Col A, Rows (10:13) and Data 2 Rows (10:13) Col A, Rows (10:13) and Data 3 Rows (10:13) Col A, Rows (10:13) and Data 4 Rows (10:13)
0   2   45  560 561 562 560             
0   2   60  609 610 611 609             
0   2   85  692 691 694 691             
0   3   60  617 617 619 618 Col A, Rows (14:15) and Data 1 Rows (14:15) Col A, Rows (14:15) and Data 2 Rows (14:15) Col A, Rows (14:15) and Data 3 Rows (14:15) Col A, Rows (14:15) and Data 4 Rows (14:15)
0   3   85  700 699 702 701             
0   4   30  520 521 522 521 Col A, Rows (16:19) and Data 1 Rows (16:19) Col A, Rows (16:19) and Data 2 Rows (16:19) Col A, Rows (16:19) and Data 3 Rows (16:19) Col A, Rows (16:19) and Data 4 Rows (16:19)
0   4   45  568 569 570 570             
0   4   60  617 617 619 618             
0   4   85  700 699 702 701
```

Please help me how I can do this for the entire dataframe and then save to a CSV file.

Here is my code for this: (but it fills up the Calculated columns with the last value calculated)

```
j = 0
i = 0
k = 0
df_length = len(df.count(1)) - 1
for row in df.iterrows():
    if (int(df.loc[k, 'X']) == int(df.loc[k+1, 'X'])):
        if (int(df.loc[k, 'Y']) == int(df.loc[k+1, 'Y'])):
            j = j + 1
        else:
           for l in range(1, 5):
               df['Calculated_'+str(l)] =      ((j+1)*sum(df.loc[i:i+j,'TEMP'+str(l)]*df.loc[i:i+j,'Data_' + str(l)])-(sum(df.loc[i:i+j,'TEMP'+str(l)])*sum(df.loc[i:i+j,'Data_'+str(l)])))/((j+1)*sum(df.loc[i:i+j,'TEMP' +_ str(l)]*df.loc[i:i+j,'TEMP' + str(l)]) - (sum(df.loc[i:i+j,'TEMP'+str(l)]))**2)
            i = i + j + 1
            j = 0
    else:
        i = i + j + 1
        j = 0
    k = k + 1
    if k == df_length:
        break
```

I would like to point out that there are two other columns X and Y, which I use to calculate the number of values I need to use to calculate the calculated column, since sometimes the data is missing for Temp for some X and Y.

Comment: So where is your code, and what exactly is wrong with it?

Comment: added the code. I would like to point out that there are two other columns X and Y, which I use to calculate the number of values I need to use to calculate the calculated column, since sometimes the data is missing for Temp for some X and Y.

Comment: **And what exactly is wrong with it?**

Comment: I am new to python and pandas (programming in general). Need to use python for some work related data crunch automation. I want to add a new column header, then for that column add the calculation for each new XY row. Repeat this for the rest of the spreadsheet. Also, the number of TEMP may vary for each XY, which I find out at the start of the loop. I am not sure how to write the statement on the left side before the = sign in the formula to achieve this, or is there a better way to achieve this? Right now it is filling the entire col with the last calculated value for that last set of XY.

Comment: In other words, how do I not make the formula fill the entire column, but only the first line of that row.

Answer (score 0):

I get what you are saying (I guess). So read the CSV file like this

```
import csv

def csv_reader(file_object):
    reader = csv.reader(file_object)

    row_count = 2
    temp_count = 0
    buffer_values = []

    for row in reader:

        # GETTING NEEDED DATA HERE

        data_1 = row[1]
        data_2 = row[2]

        buffer_values.append(row)

        temp_count += 1

        if (temp_count - row_count == 3): 

            # ACCESS THE BUFFER VALUES HERE.
            # THE BUFFER VALUES WILL HAVE DATA OF [2:5] ROWS FOR THE FIRST HIT HERE.
            # FOR THE NEXT HIT IT WILL BE [6:9]
            # IMPLEMENT YOUR FORMULAS HERE WITH data_1, data_2...

            row_count += 4
            temp_count = row_count

            # CLEAR THE BUFFER FOR NEXT RUN
            buffer_values = []
```

Now, the trick is in writing a new CSV file with all the data. You can do this before clearing the buffer every time or store all the results in another variable and then dump it to a file. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I am trying to write to the same file that I read the CSV dataframe from using df.to_csv('filename.csv')

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the code working.

Added the following to create column names:

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    data_1p8['Calculated_'+str(i)] = ''
```

Now that I have the column names, I go ahead and make a few minor changes to the loop code:

```
i = 0
j = 0
i = 0
k = 0
df_length = len(df.count(1)) - 1
for row in df.iterrows():
    if (int(df.loc[k, 'X']) == int(df.loc[k+1, 'X'])):
        if (int(df.loc[k, 'Y']) == int(df.loc[k+1, 'Y'])):
            j = j + 1
        else:
           for l in range(1, 5):
               df.loc[i,'Calculated_'+str(l)] =      ((j+1)*sum(df.loc[i:i+j,'TEMP'+str(l)]*df.loc[i:i+j,'Data_' + str(l)])-(sum(df.loc[i:i+j,'TEMP'+str(l)])*sum(df.loc[i:i+j,'Data_'+str(l)])))/((j+1)*sum(df.loc[i:i+j,'TEMP' +_ str(l)]*df.loc[i:i+j,'TEMP' + str(l)]) - (sum(df.loc[i:i+j,'TEMP'+str(l)]))**2)
            i = i + j + 1
            j = 0
    else:
        for l in range(1, 5):
               df.loc[i,'Calculated_'+str(l)] =      ((j+1)*sum(df.loc[i:i+j,'TEMP'+str(l)]*df.loc[i:i+j,'Data_' + str(l)])-(sum(df.loc[i:i+j,'TEMP'+str(l)])*sum(df.loc[i:i+j,'Data_'+str(l)])))/((j+1)*sum(df.loc[i:i+j,'TEMP' +_ str(l)]*df.loc[i:i+j,'TEMP' + str(l)]) - (sum(df.loc[i:i+j,'TEMP'+str(l)]))**2)
        i = i + j + 1
        j = 0
    k = k + 1
    if k == df_length:
        break
```

Notice that now I accessing the location of the row with variable 'i'.
Mostly, got it through some trial and error and reading a little about how to use the .loc for DataFrames.